# interact.js cursor is not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, interact.js

In the example of *interact.js* the cursor is changing on the re-size edges.
I tried the example but my cursor stays the same.

Does someone know why it wont change?

**Code:**

```
interact(obj.src[0])
  .resizable({
    invert: 'reposition',
    snap: {
      targets: [
        interact.createSnapGrid({
          x: $scope.editorOpt.gridSize,
          y: $scope.editorOpt.gridSize
        })
      ],
      range: Infinity
    },
    edges: {
      left: true,
      right: true,
      bottom: true,
      top: true
    }
  })
  .on('resizemove', function(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    let x = $(target).position().left;
    let y = $(target).position().top;
    // update the element's style
    target.style.width = event.rect.width + 'px';
    target.style.height = event.rect.height + 'px';

    // translate when resizing from top or left edges
    x += event.deltaRect.left;
    y += event.deltaRect.top;

    $(target).css("left", x + "px");
    $(target).css("top", y + "px");

    obj.style.width = event.rect.width;
    obj.style.height = event.rect.height;

    obj.style.left = x;
    obj.style.top = y;

    $scope.$apply();
  });
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the sample?

Comment: http://interactjs.io/#resizing

Comment: I created this fiddle and all seems to work, what type of element do you use? https://jsfiddle.net/qof6y2L1/

Comment: i used an input element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an updated fiddle that works with almost your code

A few remarks, I had to replace you object with a real element for the fiddles sake,

Then you probably use Angualar or something similar, so had to remove your 
    $scope.$apply(); and $scope.editorOpt.gridSize. I simply replaced that with 100.

But I think the main problem was the let. I had to replace them with var and all started to work. Please make sure to look at your console to see errors:

```
let x = $(target).position().left;
let y = $(target).position().top;
```

Changed to

```
var x = $(target).position().left;
var y = $(target).position().top;
```

I other words, I think you have a javascript error, that prevents the interact script to attach it's cursors to your element.

https://jsfiddle.net/qof6y2L1/1/

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the cursor styling like in the example by my self

**Code:**

```
this.src.mousemove(function(ev){
    if($(this).hasClass("selected")){
        let w = $(this).outerWidth(true);
        let h = $(this).outerHeight(true);
        let offset = 10;

        if((ev.offsetX <= offset && ev.offsetY <= offset) || ((w-ev.offsetX) <= offset && (h-ev.offsetY) <= offset))
            $(this).css("cursor", "nwse-resize");
        else if((ev.offsetX <= offset && (h-ev.offsetY) <= offset) || ((w-ev.offsetX) <= offset && ev.offsetY <= offset))
            $(this).css("cursor", "nesw-resize");
        else if(ev.offsetX <= offset || (w-ev.offsetX) <= offset)
            $(this).css("cursor", "ew-resize");
        else if(ev.offsetY <= offset || (h-ev.offsetY) <= offset)
            $(this).css("cursor", "ns-resize");
        else
            $(this).css("cursor", "");
    }
});
```